# Print list separated in a single row in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.x

I've got

```
data = list(a.fetchall())
print data
```

It returns:

```
[('Data1',), ('Data2',), ('Data3',), ('Data4',), ('Data5',), ('Data6',), ('Data7 ',), ('Data8',)]
```

How could I get those values separated?

I tried to use

```
print ', '.join(data)
```

But couldn't get a good return of values.

The return should be like

```
data1,data2,data3...
```

And can save the data in different variables if possible...

Comment: can you show how your output will look like??

Comment: Just like `data1,data2,data3,data4...`

Comment: Saving the data in different variables is **not** a good idea. But if you want to keep the data items separate you could save them into a new list, so it looks like `['Data1', 'Data2', 'Data3', 'Data4', 'Data5', 'Data6', 'Data7 ', 'Data8']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
', '.join(map(lambda e: e[0], data))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a list of one-item tuples. You need to extract the values from the tuples themselves.

```
', '.join(element[0] for element in data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a functional solution.

```
from operator import itemgetter

data = [
    ('Data1',), ('Data2',), ('Data3',), ('Data4',), 
    ('Data5',), ('Data6',), ('Data7 ',), ('Data8',)
]
# Extract the string from each tuple into a new list
newdata = map(itemgetter(0), data)
# Join the strings in the list into a single string
print newdata
print ', '.join(newdata)
```

**output**

```
['Data1', 'Data2', 'Data3', 'Data4', 'Data5', 'Data6', 'Data7 ', 'Data8']
Data1, Data2, Data3, Data4, Data5, Data6, Data7 , Data8
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[elem[0] for elem in data]
```